The chat history is being recorded twice, using both RunnableWithMessageHistory and RunnableLambda from LangChain
As shown in the following code, I want to create a branch in RunnableLambda, and at the destination of the branch, I want to use RunnableWithMessageHistory to generate a response considering the chat history. Currently, RunnableWithMessageHistory is also used in the full_chain that includes RunnableLambda. When I check the contents of MessagesPlaceholder in LangSmith, I notice that the history of each exchange is recorded twice. There is no problem with the result as it is, but I want to fix it to avoid unnecessary cost. Here's the code.
app = FastAPI(
    title="LangChain Server",
    version="1.0",
    description="Spin up a simple api server using Langchain's Runnable interfaces",
)

model_root = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo")
model_response = ChatOpenAI(temperature=1, model_name="gpt-4-turbo-preview")

# classification into one or two
root_prompt ="""
XXX 
Input: {input}
Classification:
"""

chain = (
    PromptTemplate.from_template(root_prompt)
    | model_root
    | StrOutputParser()
)

prompt_one = """
YYY
Input: {input}
Response:
"""

def get_session_history(user_id: str, conversation_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
    if (user_id, conversation_id) not in store:
        store[(user_id, conversation_id)] = ChatMessageHistory()
    return store[(user_id, conversation_id)]

chain_one = (
    ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            (
                "system",
                reflection_prompt,
            ),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
            ("human", "{input}"),
        ]
    )
    | model_response
)

chain_one_memory = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    chain_one,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="input",
    history_messages_key="history",
    history_factory_config=[
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="user_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="User ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the user.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="conversation_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="Conversation ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the conversation.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
    ],
)

question_two = """
ZZZ
Input: {input}
Question:
"""

chain_two = (
    ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            (
                "system",
                question_prompt,
            ),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
            ("human", "{input}"),
        ]
    )
    | model_response
)

chain_two_memory = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    chain_two,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="input",
    history_messages_key="history",
    history_factory_config=[
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="user_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="User ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the user.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="conversation_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="Conversation ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the conversation.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
    ],
)

def route(info):
    if "one" in info["topic"].lower():
        return chain_one_memory
    else:
        return chain_two_memory

# RunnableLambda
full_chain = {
    "topic": chain,
    "input": lambda x: x["input"]} | RunnableLambda(
        route,
     )

store = {}

chain_with_history = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    full_chain,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="input",
    history_messages_key="history",
    history_factory_config=[
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="user_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="User ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the user.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="conversation_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="Conversation ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the conversation.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
    ],
)

add_routes(
    app,
    chain_with_history,
    disabled_endpoints=["playground", "batch"],
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

Of course, I considered the following method of not using RunnableWithMessageHistory for full_chain, but I get an error. 
Here is the corrected version:
# RunnableLambda
full_chain = {
    "topic": chain,
    "input": lambda x: x["input"]} | RunnableLambda(
        route,
     )

store = {}

add_routes(
    app,
    full_chain,
    disabled_endpoints=["playground", "batch"],
)


ValueError: Missing keys ['conversation_id', 'user_id'] in config['configurable'] Expected keys are ['conversation_id', 'user_id'].When using via .invoke() or .stream(), pass in a config; e.g., chain.invoke({'input': 'foo'}, {'configurable': {'conversation_id': '[your-value-here]', 'user_id': '[your-value-here]'}})

I wonder if there is a way to avoid double recording the dialogue history. I would like to see a full_chain that includes RunnableLambda, and a way to convey the config information to the destination of the branch.
